# How to change calendar week start day in Android?

Tags: motorola-droid, calendar

I prefer my week view of my calendar to start on Monday rather than Sunday. I already have my Google Calendar set that way (to which I sync).

How can I do the same on my Droid (Android 2.2)?

Comment: I wanna make the start day Saturday, any way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is apparently not possible on a Motorola Droid with Android 2.1.

<del>FroYo is slated to release next week. Maybe it will also change the ability to set this value. (If it does I'll change this answer.)</del>

Sadly, this is still not possible with Android 2.2 either.

Comment: For what it's worth, I am able to do this on my Galaxy Nexus (Android 4.0) and, presumably, going forward, using the stock calendar.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not exactly sure whether it's the same on general Android as my have a Hero with Sense but on my phone it's:

Open Calendar/Press Menu Key/ Press More/ Settings/Calendar View Settings/First day of the Week

Comment: Unfortunately, no such setting exists on my Droid.

Answer (score 3):

The popular home screen replacement LauncherPro Plus comes with a home screen widget that does just this and sync's with your Google calendar

Answer (score 3):

I just found the way to change start day of the week in Calendar app. It's related to Language ("Locale" in pre-2.3) settings:

- "English (United Kingdom)" sets Monday as the start day of the week.
- "English (United States)" sets Sunday as the start day of the week.

Where to find this option:

- Android 2.1 Eclair (Samsung Galaxy Spica)

  - at Home screen -> [Menu] button -> Settings -> Language & Keyboard -> Select locale
- Android 2.3.7 Gingerbread, (Sony Ericson Xperia ST25i)

  - at Home screen -> [Menu] button -> Settings -> Language & Keyboard -> Select language

Comment: Sadly, there is no such setting on the Motorola Droid.

Answer (score 1):

1. Uninstall the app.
2. Cange the language of the device to an European one (English UK or Spanish)
3. Go to Play Store and download the Google Calendar app. Install it.
   Now the week starts on a Monday
4. Change the language of your device back to your previous one (English US)
5. The week starts on Monday.

It worked for me.